Using ExplSyntax with tasks to create a custom \item command - Making \item backwards compatible
The MWE example below uses ExplSyntax to create a custom \item command that can be used within the tasks package (to format a solution with each item):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\itemX}{m O{}}{%
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \task #1 \\ \textit{Solution:} ~ #2 }
}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{mytasks}
  {
    O{} % optional options
    D(){1} % number of columns
  }
  {
    \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
  }
  {
    \my_task_make:nnV {#1} {#2} \l_tmpa_tl
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \my_task_make:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \begin{tasks}[#1](#2) #3 \end{tasks}
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \my_task_make:nnn {nnV}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\section*{Example Task Lists}

\begin{mytasks}(2)
  \itemX{First item}[This is the solution]
 % \item This causes an error
  \itemX{Third item}
  \itemX{Fourth item}
  \itemX{Fifth item}
  \itemX{Sixth item}
\end{mytasks}

\end{document}

First suggested here Wrapping the Tasks Command in a New Environment.
As per line 33, I cannot seem to get a regular \item to work within this configuration. Ideally, I am trying to have \item #1 function as \itemX{#1}.

please don't edit solutions into your question.

Since \item is not something that tasks expects, you just want to use \task.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\taskX}{m O{}}{#1 \\ \textit{Solution:} ~ #2 }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mytasks}
  {
    O{} % optional options
    D(){1} % number of columns
    +b % gather the contents
  }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #3 }
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { \taskX } { \task \taskX }
  }
  {
    \my_task_make:nnV {#1} {#2} \l_tmpa_tl
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \my_task_make:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \begin{tasks}[#1](#2) #3 \end{tasks}
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \my_task_make:nnn {nnV}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\section*{Example Task Lists}

\begin{mytasks}(2)
  \taskX{First item}[This is the solution]
  \task This causes no error
  \taskX{Third item}
  \taskX{Fourth item}
  \taskX{Fifth item}
  \taskX{Sixth item}
\end{mytasks}

\end{document}



This is a great solution. Coupled with:
\NewTasksEnvironment{tasks_custom}[\item]
\item seems to be able to be used safely. I will edit my MWE with this, but obviously need to give this to you for a perfect solution.
